# How to make GitHub correctly show the build status image of the Jenkins Build Status plugin

Tags: github, jenkins

Here's an example of a project:

https://github.com/storm-enroute/macrogl

The `README.md` of this project contains a build status image from a Jenkins running on a server somewhere else:

```
[![Build Status](https://ci.storm-enroute.com:8080/job/public-macrogl/badge/icon)](https://ci.storm-enroute.com:8080/job/public-macrogl/)
```

This image is rendered perfectly in Stackoverflow and Github static pages, but on the Github website it is cached to the content delivery network called Fastly. Opening the image URL shows "Not found".

- Why is this happening?
- How do I have the Github web interface render a markdown with such an image correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I have the Github web interface render a markdown with such an image correctly?

The syntax is correct.

Some other project leverage such feature (see **[LibGit2Sharp Readme](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/README.md#current-project-build-status)** or **[libgit2 Readme](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/README.md)** for instance).

> Why is this happening?

Few seconds ago, https://ci.storm-enroute.com:8080/job/public-macrogl/badge/icon was returning a 404 for me. It looks now fixed.

However, there's a possibility that when the CI server is offline/can't be reached, the 404 is temporarily cached by **[Camo](https://github.com/atmos/camo)** and served until the cache expires.

Comment: It was mistakenly offline a bit ago, but generally it is online all the time. Do you think it is possible to force GitHub to refresh?

Comment: @axel22 Through the UI, you can't. It'll eventually refresh. If you want to speed things up, drop a mail at support@github.com. They're usually pretty cool and eager to help.

Comment: I contacted their support and they said it was due to an SSL issue with my server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407884/configuring-jenkins-with-startssl-adding-the-issuer-chain

Answer (score 0):

1. install jenkins plugin for embeddable-build-status from: https://plugins.jenkins.io/embeddable-build-status
2. add to your README.md the tags you want:

**Plain Link (with view)**

http://URL:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=JOB_NAME

**Plain Link (without view)**

http://URL:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=JOB_NAME

**Markdown (with view)**

[Build Status http://URL:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=JOB_NAME](http://URL:8080/job/JOB_NAME/)

**Markdown (without view)**

[Build Status http://URL:8080/buildStatus/icon?job=JOB_NAME](http://URL:8080/job/JOB_NAME)

3.Configure jenkins security to allow the status view:
Manage Jenkins -> Configure Security -> Authorization -> choose matrix-based security and check the "ViewStatus" box for the Anonymous user.
if admin user is not there, add it and give it permission to all the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else spending way more time than intended on this and wanting a little clarity on what link(s) to use after installing the Emeddable Build Status plugin:

If you navigate to the job in the Jenkins (jenkins_home >> repo >> project >> branch), there's a "Emeddable Build Status" widget you can click on the left pane, and it'll show list exactly what links you can use for your specific jobs.

[image]

The following URL structure might also get you to the embeddable build status page:

https://<jenkins_host>/job/<github_owner_or_org>/job/<github_repo_name>/job/master/badge/

Update: I had a similar issue. It turned that the cache server requires the image to be hosted behind a HTTPS, with a fully valid SSL certificate chain (CA(s) + cert). Once your server provides the full cert chain, github will display your badge.