# Configuring Jenkins with StartSSL - adding the issuer chain

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I am unable to correctly configure Jenkins to use a StartSSL certificate.
I'm running it with command line arguments that specify paths to the private key and my certificate as shown on the Jenkins Wiki (at the bottom: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins).

- I've obtained a private key and a certificate from StartSSL
- I've placed them in a particular folder
- I'm running Jenkins as follows: `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080 --httpsCertificate=<mydomain.crt file> --httpsPrivateKey=<my private key file>`

Jenkins starts successfully. Opening `https://mydomain:8080/` in Firefox says that the connection is untrusted:

```
mydomain:8080 uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

I've tried verifying `mydomain:8080` on various SSL checker websites:

```
OK mydomain resolves to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

OK The certificate was issued by StartCom.  

OK The certificate will expire in XXX days. 

OK The hostname (mydomain) is correctly listed in the certificate.

Not OK The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers.
       You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate
       to link it to a trusted root certificate.
```

StartSSL does not have explicit instructions for setting up Jenkins. I've tried following up on similar tutorials for other kinds of servers, and copied the intermediate authority files from StartCom into a unified certificate (`ca.pem` and `sub.class1.server.ca.pem` as noted here: http://www.startssl.com/?app=42).

However, this did not change anything.

SSL checkers like www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html‎ still report that the website is untrusted.
Also, the GitHub image caching service is not rendering the build status icon from Jenkins for the same reason.

How do I add the issuer chain correctly to my certificate?

Comment: Have you tried opening the website in a different browser? Firefox seems to have an aversion StartCom certificates. Also, check that the concatenated certificate is correctly formed (i.e. END and BEGIN are on separate lines)

Comment: Yes, they are on separate lines. In IE it seems to work without a certificate, as well as Opera Mobile. However, GitHub still seems to be caching the build status images from my web browser incorrectly, and the certificate checking websites also complain.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem and after some research what got everything to be trusted was :

1. Merged the intermediate authority certificate and `<mydomain.crt file>` into 1 unified certificate called `merged.cer` using the link you mentioned
2. (From: https://serverfault.com/questions/569866/jenkins-wont-serve-with-ca-signed-certificate)

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -inkey /location/to/key.pem -in /location/to/merged.cer  -export -out keys.pkcs12

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keys.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore jenkins.jks
   ```

NOTE: the key to use for the `merged.cer` should be the same as `<my private key file>`

Then follow the Jenkins Wiki to use the KeyStore instead of the certificate

```
    java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8080 --httpsKeyStore=/path/to/jenkins.jks --httpsPrivateKey=<my private key file>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. But my command is a little bit different as I am following the [jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins): `JENKINS_ARGS=" --httpsKeyStore=/var/lib/jenkins/ssl/startssl.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=mypassword "` This is edited from Centos jenkins `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file.

Comment: How come you don't need --httpsKeyStorePassword?